# Run app on newest versions of Socket.IO gratter than 1.0

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I need some help to make a code writed to Socket.IO < 0.9 works with newers versions, like 1.3:

```
var port = 843;

var io = require('socket.io').listen( port );
io.enable('browser client minification');  // send minified client
io.enable('browser client etag');          // apply etag caching logic based on version number
io.enable('browser client gzip');          // gzip the file
//io.set('log level', 1);  

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('woot_send', function(op){
    socket.broadcast.emit('woot_receive', op);
    if( op.type == 'cursor-create' && Object.keys(io.connected).length == 1 )
      socket.emit('woot_receive', {type: 'contents-init', contents: "Sample initial content that might be coming from permanent storage..."});
  });
  socket.on('woot_save', function(contents){
    console.log(contents);
  });
});
```

It causes the error:

```
/home/celso/woot/node/app.js:4
io.enable('browser client minification');  // send minified client
   ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/celso/woot/node/app.js:4:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minification, etag and gzip were removed from `socket.io` since version 1.0.0. `io.enable` function does not exist anymore with the API and that is why it throws an error. 
SocketIO now provides a CDN with gzip compression and minified version. Use this to enable your clients to use the CDN.

`<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>`

SocketIO when introduced 1.0.0, specified CDN delivery methods which are [described here](http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/#cdn-delivery). Specifically, the CDN (provided by Google zopfli) provides high level of zip compression, proper support for caching and built-in SSL support.

The recommendations from SocketIO Author are: [Originally listed in this closed Pull Request](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/1847)

- /socket/socket.io.js is meant for development. It can work in production, of course, but it won't be optimized
- The CDN provides all the more advanced features that would otherwise bloat our codebase (minification, compression, caching).
- Ultimately, if opting not to use the CDN, it's best to use socket.io as part of a build system (like webpack or browserify), and introduce minification and compression for the entire build, not each component.

An old [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23981741/minify-socket-io-socket-io-js-with-1-0) on the same topic exists here, but does not include the latest version from the CDN.

If you face issues other than `io.enable`, there is a guide to [migrating from 0.9 to higher versions of SocketIO](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/).

So, you should remove the lines using `io.enable` function from version 0.9 and enable the clients to use `socket.io` from the CDN listed above.